# Is there a Future/Promise equivalent of C++ in D?

Tags: concurrency, d

Does there exist a future/promise equivalent from the C++ world in the D world?

Sure there is [std.parallelism](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_parallelism.html) but it's doesn't have exactly the functionality of the promise/future combination (there is no equivalent to get the future or the set the result or the exception, you can't also wait for completion).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you did not seriously look at `std.parallelism`... Equivalent to "get the future" (if by that you mean the `std::future`'s get() method) are yieldForce(), spinForce() and workForce(). Read about these more carefully and you will see that you *can* wait for completion as well...

std::future::get() *waits until the future has a valid result and (depending on which template is used) retrieves it*. That is exactly what yieldForce does.

About exceptions... Where did you see you can't get an exception??
From the [std.parallelism](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_parallelism.html) page: *If the Task isn't started yet, execute it in the current thread. If it's done, return its return value, if any. If it's in progress, wait on a condition variable. **If it threw an exception, rethrow that exception**.*

std.parallelism "suffers" from not trying to copy C++ and/or Java and people who come from these communities always expect things to behave as they are used to (been there, done that).

Someone correct me, but std.parallelism pre-dates std::future and std::promise, right?

Comment: but i can't set the result of it from a specific thread like it is possible in c++ without some tricks